# Hangfire with horizontal scaling

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, hangfire

I want to make use of the `hangfire` library to run recurring tasks. For the simplicity of this question.

I simply want to run 1 task every 5 minutes.

I have setup `hangfire` normally. It points to my database. I then push my web project to my azure web app. And all runs happily. Every 5 minutes my task gets run.

But now in the case when my demand increases, and I go and auto or manually scale my web servers, to 3 instances.

Will this task get executed on ALL 3 server instances?

How can I design it so that the task only gets executed ONCE, regardless of which server or instance created that task.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you are using Azure, why wouldn't you use Azure Functions or webjobs to run recurring tasks?

Comment: I am using azure.  I will look into those.  ATM the project is all contained into one web project and is easy to manage when all code is in the same place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the docs](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/running-multiple-server-instances.html):

> It is possible to run multiple server instances inside a process,
>   machine, or on several machines at the same time. Each server use
>   distributed locks to perform the coordination logic.

I.e. you will have 3 instances of Hangfire but the individual job will only get executed by one of them, however, this may not be on the same server each time. In order to do this, you can follow this StackOverflow answer which involves assigning the job to a queue that is specific to the server you want the processing to happen on: [hangfire recurring job on every server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42201809/hangfire-recurring-job-on-every-server/42202844)

Comment: Ok that is perfect, so my desired operation is build in by default.

Comment: Does anyone know how to split the workload of jobs evenly between different servers, each having their own connection to the same HF Job Database ?