# How to dispatch Hangfire jobs on all Azure available instances?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service, hangfire

I have a Web Api app running on Azure. I run each morning a scheduler job at 2:00AM that creates a lot of hangfire jobs.

At this time, the Web Api app has only one available instance that is configure to scale out based on CPU metrics. These running hangfire jobs increase the CPU percentage to the limit and create new available instances of the api app.

Unfortunately, it seems to me a given hangfire job runs on the instance that created it. How can I configure Hangfire to dispatch jobs on all the available instances ?

Comment: Please consider Azure Functions instead of Hangfire jobs when you run your application on the cloud. It should be a better approach: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview. Example: Azure automatically scales for you, if you use consumption plan, you would pay only for the time that your code runs,....

Answer (score 4):

> Unfortunately, it seems to me a given hangfire job runs on the instance that created it. How can I configure Hangfire to dispatch jobs on all the available instances ?

AFAIK, the job would in the `default` queue by default. If you run multiple server instances, the job would be distributed to available instances. For testing, I just adding my tasks as follows:

```
Enumerable.Range(11, 30).ForEach(i =>
{
    BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => Console.WriteLine($"[Task-{i}] Getting Started with HangFire!"));
});
```

Then, processing the jobs in a console application as follows:

```
using (var server = new BackgroundJobServer())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hangfire Server started. Press any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I started two server instances and I got the following result:

[image]

Moreover, for configuring Job Queues you could follow [here](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/configuring-queues.html). Also, here is an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42201809/hangfire-recurring-job-on-every-server/42202844) that is the opposite of your issue about running a job only on one server instance.

Comment: I already noticed the jobs distribution using a Web API and a VM on Azure. When using only a Web API configured to autoscale, I didn't see any dispatch but I will retry it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this behavior may be connected with [this pull request](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/pull/520) which adds zero-latency job processing when job is queued and processed on the same instance.

Looking through the code I see we `WaitAny` for event that is `Set` whenever we add new job to queue. Then we try to fetch job from queue again. This reduces job latency as it gets picked up sooner.

My hypothesis is that multiple jobs will distribute to your other instance whenever current instance is busy.